# need assistance with ansible loop command

Tags: ansible

I am trying to put a "loop" condition to check status of filesystem until it gets mounted.  File system is getting mounted but task reporting failure.  Could someone assist what is wrong in this block.

Trying to resize gcp compute machine and waiting for filesystems to get mounted before i start remaining processes

```
- set_fact:
    data_fs: /var/data
    
- debug:
    var: data_fs

- set_fact:
    commit_fs: /var/commitlog

- debug:
    var: commit_fs

- name: Wait for data mount point
  stat: path={{ data_fs }}
  register: data_fs_status
  until: data_fs_status.stat.exists == "true"
  retries: 10
  delay: 6

- name: Wait for commit mount point
  stat: path={{ commit_fs }}
  register: commit_fs_status
  until: commit_fs_status.stat.exists == "true"
  retries: 10
  delay: 6

- include: start.yaml
```

Output getting is as below
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for data mount point (10 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for data mount point (9 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for data mount point (8 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for data mount point (7 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for data mount point (6 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for data mount point (5 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for data mount point (4 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for data mount point (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for data mount point (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait for data mount point (1 retries left).

stat:
atime: 1660251304.4672601
attr_flags: e
attributes:
- extents
block_size: 4096
blocks: 8
charset: binary
ctime: 1615927045.570012
dev: 2064
device_type: 0
executable: true
exists: true => output of stat.exists is showing true but loop returning false.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is `until: commit_fs_status.stat.exists == "true"` will never Succeed. This statement will never return a string of "true". stat.exists will only ever return a boolean. See below for what should fix your problem and here is a link to the stat.exists doc.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#return-stat/exists

```
- set_fact:
    data_fs: /var/data
    commit_fs: /var/commitlog
    
- debug:
    msg: 
      - "{{ data_fs }}"
      - "{{ commit_fs }}"

- name: Wait for data mount point
  stat: 
    path: "{{ data_fs }}"
  register: data_fs_status
  until: data_fs_status.stat.exists # No need to do an equals, .exists returns a boolean
  retries: 10
  delay: 6

- name: Wait for commit mount point
  stat: 
    path: "{{ commit_fs }}"
  register: commit_fs_status
  until: commit_fs_status.stat.exists # No need to do an equals, .exists returns a boolean
  retries: 10
  delay: 6

- include: start.yaml
```